# How can I get gold faster in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I want to know how to get gold faster in Clash of Clans, so I can upgrade my town hall to level 8.

I tried upgrading my mines but  it made no difference. I attacked people with 200k loot but it made no difference (it gets robbed).

Answer (score 12):

If you don't mind losing trophies, a good strategy is to put your town hall on the outside of your base. Then using a [bulkhead](http://www.clashofclans-tools.com/Base-Design-Guide) base design, focus all of your defenses to protecting your resources.

I typically hover around 1k trophies this way. Most people that attack me will just go for the Town Hall and leave my huge defenses alone. This gives me a free 12 hour shield when they do so as well.

Just a note: if you cannot protect your resources at Town Hall 7, then you're going to lose even more resources at Town Hall 8. The bigger the difference in Town Hall levels between players greatly affects how many resources they can take.

Comment: Not surprisingly, this is outdated. Shield's are not given if less than some percentage (50% I think it is).  Just to beware some unfortunate reader.

Answer (score 2):

(Free way)Enter a clan that requires nothing to subscribe to, and improve your defense, specially invest in your city walls. If you win wars your clan receives money you can cash in afterwards.

If you are willing to spend some bucks on it, first upgrade all your gold mines until there's no more upgrade you can make, then buy a short-span shield (1 day, 3 days) and boost all of your mines (gems required). This could help you achieve a huge amount of gold in a short time.

Comment: Ok. Thx. That helped

Answer (score 0):

Just raid people with lots of loot and don't raid for the trophies raid for the loot!

Answer (score -1):

1. upgrade your troops to the max (to get the loot)
2. upgrade your defense to the max (to keep your resources)
3. and then pick attacking base wisely (to be efficient with the use of your resources in your troop)
4. pick suitable trophy range: for town hall 7, it should be around 1000-1350 trophies.

By the way, why attack people with 200K loot? It is not that common, and sometimes these bases are difficult to attack. 100K is fine, if the base is easy to attack.

Comment: Why *not* attack people with 200k loot if you find one? When it's easy for the grab, grab it and since it's rare, that's even more the reason to do so. Your last line doesn't make any sense because any easy base with more resources than the amount you used to build your army is good for raid if it's easy to get the resources.

Comment: @jerry He is in TH7,He meant TH8 Bases with upgraded defences. well attacking bases with collectors outside isnt a bad idea. but pointlessly trying to attack bases with storages in **core** of high lvl base with low level troops wont budge.

Comment: @Fennekin Still doesn't change anything. BARCH works for abandoned bases and those usually have more than 200k of each resource. Upgraded defenses has no effect on BARCH because the number of troops overwhelm the speed at which defenses fire.

Comment: @jerry Barch is a awesome strategy if one knows how to use it properly. but core type bases (walls lvl8) cannot be barched unless you have archer queen

Comment: @Fennekin right, but be aware that Latinlotus is generalising his statement in his answer. He is saying not to attack any base with 200k loot, whether in the core or not and that just doesn't make sense.