# Best place to put Town Hall when farming

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am currently a farming town hall 7, and I am debating where to put my Town Hall. I have seen people put their Town Hall in the corner of their village with bombs surrounding it. However, I have also seen people put it near to their walls.

I am trying to keep a steady trophy level while also gaining loot. I am currently in Silver 1 and have my base at a maxed out Town Hall 6.

What is the best place to put my town hall?

Comment: Hmm... to me, this sounds more like a question with an opinionated answer. I don't know though, it probably has a well thought out solution.

Comment: I just want a way to maximize loot. I didn't think of it as opinionated.

Comment: If you're going for max loot, there's [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170222/how-can-i-get-gold-faster-in-clash-of-clans) that might help you out.

Comment: Even with your TH in a corner of your base, if you're raiding successfully then you will easily keep your trophy count at a certain level.  The point is that you don't want people to raid you for resources, so you sacrifice trophies for a 12 hour shield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your cups when farming, [look into hybrid bases.](https://www.google.com/search?q=clash%20of%20clans%20hybrid%20base%20th7&biw=1920&bih=899&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=5IMpVO2RKIu2yATZrYKwCg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg)

Otherwise, when farming, you should just have your town hall in any corner of the map, away from your defenses & resources, so your opponents are tempted with the easy win by destroying just your town hall and not go for your resources.  (IMO don't bother putting any defensive items such as bombs or traps near it.  Save that protection to cover your resources)

As boiledham mentioned in the chat above, they will get only a few trophies and you will gain a 12 hour shield.